# Zend Framework :: Ajax Requests

Tags: ajax, zend-framework

I am looking out for any library that would facilitate Ajax in Zend (if any exist). Also can somebody throw some light on the built-in Ajax support that comes with ZF.
I tried googling but was not satisfied with the results.

-DevD

Comment: if not any Library, May be some kind of AsyncronusController that would handle/route the Ajax request across the app ?

Comment: I would be interested in something that makes Zend_Forms different elements & decorators available through jquery.

Answer (score 2):

altough JQuery is well integrated with the Zend Framework. There is an libray inside the /extras Folder.

There are helpers for AjaxRequests, different View Widgets, and for loading the Library from Google/AOL CDN.

For more information i would suggest to visit the Zend Framework Documentation for :

[ZendX Jquery](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.html)

Comment: Beware: the documentation of `ZendX_JQuery` is unexisting. It's a good component for really basic ajax-solutions though.

Comment: yup ZendX_JQuery is somthing similar I was looking upto. @chelmertz: you are right, there doesnt exist any specific detail documentation for the same.
though I found something @ http://all4you.net/ZendFramework-1.10.1/extras/documentation/manual/extras/en/zendx.jquery.html#zendx.jquery.introduction

Answer (score 1):

Dojo is shipped with the Zend Framework and they facilitate ajax style calls.

If you have a look at [Dojo ToolKit](http://dojotoolkit.org) to find out more about the what that framework can provide you, these include the ajax calls (search for xhrGet and xhrPost)

Also if you look here in the framework documentation to help you use dojo in your Zend Framework Project. [Zend_Dojo](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dojo.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Grant for the info, Nice to see Zend-Dojo sync up. but I would rather prefer Jquery over DoJo unless n until it eases up my work with some build in support from ZF (may be few helpers functions) to dojo.

Comment: where is the difference between my and your link?

Answer (score 1):

If you have any expertise in YUI JS framework, it is really easy to listen to the events and make Ajax calls and to collect your elements through Selector query and then apply CSS rules on them (if that is what you want). You can have a look at this tutorial to understand more about Zend-YUI relationship

http://ciitronian.com/blog/programming/javascript/creating-ajax-based-form-zend-framework-yui/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Zend Framwork 2 module.

If you do not have a application you can use the Wasabilib Skeleton https://github.com/WasabiLib/wasabilib_zf2_skeleton_application. It comes with all necessary assets in the right place.

If you already have an application you should only clone the module not the full skeleton.

Minimal requirements: jQuery, ZF2

1. Add the module to application.config.php.
2. Include the wasabilib.min.js after jquery in the head of your layout.phtml

**How it works**
in your .phtml-file you have a form like this:

```
<form id="simpleForm" class="ajax_element" action="simpleFormExample" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="written_text">
<input type="submit" value="try it">
</form>
```

Anywhere else in your phtml you can place an element where the response is shown.

In your Controller the following method:

```
public function simpleFormExampleAction(){
    $postArray = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $input = $postArray['written_text'];
    $response = new Response(new InnerHtml("#element_simple_form","Server     Response: ".$input));
    return $this->getResponse()->setContent($response);
}
```

The form has a class "ajax_element" this will say the the library that the request will be done with an xmlhttp-request. **It wont work if you do not give an id to the requesting element**. So the form has the ID "simpleForm". The action is the "path/to/controller" just like a normal request.

In the controller action a new WasabiLib\Ajax\Response object is instanciated.
The InnerHtml class is for replace, prepend and append html or normal text to a selector. 
In this case the selector is an ID "element_simple_form". The first parameter of the InnerHtml class is the selector. **Make sure that you write #yourElementId or .yourClassSelector**. For IDs an "#" and for class selectors "."

The second parameter is the Text you want to fill in this element.

The response object can handle a lot more responses which you can add with

```
$response->add($anotherResponseType);
```

A list of possible response types is on its homepage wasabilib.org

The module is build to handle ajax request an responses in a very simple way. Once you have understood the behavior you can handle almost every practical ajax need.